# DDS reliable reader getting same messages on application restart

Tags: messaging, publish-subscribe, qos, data-distribution-service

I have an RTI DDS application with a `reliable reader` and `reliable writer`.

Whenever I restart the reader application, the reader reads messages it already received. So in the case the reader received a message to restart the application it is now in a restart loop due to the restart message being read every application restart.

I was under the impression that these messages would be acknowledged and not resent if already received before application restart. Why am I receiving messages I thus have already read on application restart of the reader? Also is there a way to see if the messages are being acknowledged as sent and received?

Comment: Do your QoS settings for the Writer and Reader happen to include a TRANSIENT_LOCAL policy for the Durability QoS?

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek yes it does include that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your QoS settings have a `TRANSIENT_LOCAL` policy for Durability, you are observing expected behavior. According to [this documentation](https://community.rti.com/static/documentation/connext-dds/5.2.3/doc/api/connext_dds/api_cpp/group__DDSDurabilityQosModule.html), the effect of using `TRANSIENT_LOCAL` is that "RTI Connext will attempt to keep some samples so that they can be delivered to any potential late-joining DDSDataReader." -- as required by the OMG DDS specification. That is exactly what you see happening.

If you do not want that kind of behavior, select the `VOLATILE` policy for Durability on your Writer and Reader.

Comment: will this then keep reliability for any missed messages or no?

Comment: Yes, it will. You should keep the setting of RELIABLE policy for the [reliability QoS](https://community.rti.com/static/documentation/connext-dds/5.2.3/doc/api/connext_dds/api_cpp/group__DDSReliabilityQosModule.html).

Comment: thanks! sounds like this is the way to go in that case.